# Update process from within method called by backgroundworker c#

Tags: c#, events, backgroundworker

I have an application with a gui and a `Rich Text Box` where I output what the program is currently doing since data processing can be quite long.

I tried two approaches for that:

1 In the Backgroundworker method I can just call the following code fine:

```
GlobalVar.backgroundWorkerAppendText = task.Build_CSV_List();
Processchange();
```

Whereas I cannot use `Form1.Processchange();` in the helper class due to the non static context

2 Therefore I tried to create my very first eventhandler.
The Idea was that helper.UpdateConsole() would raise an event

```
public event EventHandler OnConsoleUpdate;
public void Consoleupdate()
{
    OnConsoleUpdate(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

to which the Backgroundworker listens and then calls Processchange from its context

```
public void BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    StandardTasks task = new StandardTasks();
    Helper helper = new Helper();
    helper.OnConsoleUpdate += Processchange;
    task.DoSomeStuffHere()
}
public void Processchange(object sender=null, EventArgs e=null)
{
    //MessageBox.Show(GlobalVar.backgroundWorkerAppendText);
    GlobalVar.next = false;
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(1);
    while (GlobalVar.next == false)
    {
        helper.TimeBreaker(100,"ms");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this was was not successful. As soon as rising the Event I get the errormessage `System.NullReferenceException` which -after googling- leads me to the conclusion that there is no listerner attached to the event eventhouh I attached it in the Backgroundworker Do work.

Edit: the OnConsoleUpdate() == null as shown on the screenshot below

[event = null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVCys.png)

The helper is in another class file "helpers" which might be important for a solution.

i hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: Is it an option to switch to Task-based Async Pattern (TAP)? Then you could just start a Task on the ThreadPool and pass it a Progress object. If you want to stick with the Backgroundworker, you need to show more of the relevant code.

Comment: Where did you start this background worker ? I meand something like that: backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

Comment: BTW: Having a class "GlobalVar" ... that has some code smell ...

Comment: You should always check for null before raising your events: `OnConsoleUpdate?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);`

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: @Fildor I have unfortunately no clue what a TAP is; GlobalVar.backgroundWorkerAppendText is actually no code but a string so i can easily access it from anywhere

Comment: @Arkadiusz in the form I have a "startbutton" which calls the Backgroundworker

Comment: @Szabolcs Dézsi what does your code do?

Comment: @julianbechtold The answer to that is in @Shaamaan’s answer below in the linked MSDN page.

Comment: Please check the edit to my answer, @julianbechtold. There seems to be a clear error how the `task` and `helper` classes interact (or, rather, how they DON'T interact, but based on your expectations, they should).

Comment: _"I have unfortunately no clue what a TAP is"_ TAP is the TLA for "Taskbased Asynchronous Pattern" i.e. "`async/await Task`" It would be the more "state of the art" way to do this. But it would mean a major code change, so I guess it is out of question.

Comment: Also see https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-round-1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

A few things immediately jump to mind.

First, let's get the event issue out of the way. You've got the correct approach - you need an event and method to call it, but that method should check if the event is `null`.

Basically, do this:

```
public event EventHandler OnConsoleUpdate;
public void ConsoleUpdate()
{
    OnConsoleUpdate?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

The above makes use of `?`, a null-condition operator. You can read more about it [on this MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators).

Second thing... it's unclear what your background worker actually IS. It sounds like it's some kind of custom class you crated? The reason it's important is because .NET actually has a [`BackgroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.95).aspx) class used for running operations... well, in the background. It also has an `OnProgressChanged` event which you can hook up to which could be used to update the UI (just remember to set the `WorkerReportsProgress` property to `true`). And to use the `BackgroundWorker` mentioned above, you shouldn't need to create any events of your own.

Here's how you can use the standard .NET `BackgroundWorker`:

```
System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker worker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();

void StartBackgroundTask()
{
    worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    //if it's possible to display progress, use this
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
    //what to do when the method finishes?
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    //start!
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //perform any "finalization" operations, like re-enable disabled buttons
    //display the result using the data in e.Result
    //this code will be running in the UI thread
}

//example of a container class to pass more data in the ReportProgress event
public class ProgressData
{
    public string OperationDescription { get; set; }
    public int CurrentResult { get; set; }
    //feel free to add more stuff here
}

void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //display the progress using e.ProgressPercentage or e.UserState
    //this code will be running in the UI thread
    //UserState can be ANYTHING:
    //var data = (ProgressData)e.UserState;
}

void worker_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //this code will NOT be running in the UI thread!
    //you should NOT call the UI thread from this method

    int result = 1;
    //perform calculations
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        worker.ReportProgress(i, new ProgressData(){ OperationDescription = "CustomState passed as second, optional parameter", CurrentResult = result });
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        result *= i;
    }

    e.Result = result;
}
```

Now, the thing about the `BackgroundWorker` class is that it is rather old, and with current .NET versions you can use the `async / await` keywords to easily handle background operations and UI updates, but this probably is going outside the bounds of this question. That said, the existence of `async / await` doesn't invalidate the use of `BackgroundWorker` which is pretty simple in its usage.

There's one more worrisome thing in your code.

```
public void BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    StandardTasks task = new StandardTasks(); //<- you create a task
    Helper helper = new Helper(); // <- you create a helper
    helper.OnConsoleUpdate += Processchange; // <- you hook up to the helper event
    task.DoSomeStuffHere(); // <- you do stuff with the task... but the task doesn't know about your helper above! Does `StandardTasks` use `Helper`? If so, how?
}
```

Do note that events, unless made `static`, aren't global. So hooking up to an event in one instance of a class won't cause another instance of that class to "fire" that event. It seems one way to fix your issues would be to make the `StandardTasks` class take `Helper` as one of the constructor parameters, so the code would look like this:

```
Helper helper = new Helper(); // <- you create a helper
helper.OnConsoleUpdate += Processchange; // <- you hook up to the helper class event to actually do something
StandardTasks task = new StandardTasks(helper); //<- you create a task which will use the helper with the hooked up event above
```

Comment: Checking the event handler for null like this is not safe and can still result in an exception, because an added handler can get removed between the check for null and invoking the handler. I recommend using the null conditional operator (?.) or saving the OnConsoleUpdate to a local variable and using that for the null check and invocation.

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi You're absolutely correct. I'll edit the answer. Albeit, to be fair, that WAS the standard way of handling events before the ? operator was added I believe...

Comment: Hello Shaamaan, thank you for your help. your code actually is what i have in my code but its not working. for the backgroubndworker i "pulled" it from the tools window in the form designer. I can also do a  Processchanged but only directly from within the backgroundworker. not from a method it has called.

Comment: @julianbechtold Please, in the future, make sure to capitalize the words correctly. Whenever I see code-formatted text on SO, I assume it's actually copy-pasted code. In this case, `Backgroundworker` (without proper capitalization) wouldn't actually work. You also wrote about creating your own even, which is pointless when using the actual .NET `BackgroundWorker`. I'll edit the answer with a sample `BackgroundWorker` implementation.

Comment: @Shaamaan Okay thank you. I have added the ?invoke. The application doesn't crash anymore but the event isnt sent either. I have debugged and it seems that "OnConsoleUpdate == null". How can I change this? What information can i provide that would help clearing up the issue? My Backgroundworker looks pretty much the same than yours in the example. Best regards, Julian

Comment: @Shaamaan bregarding your last "worriesome" edit: I made this to make my code non-static. The StandardTasks has implemented the helper class the same way with Helper help = new Helper

Comment: @julianbechtold In which case this won't work. If the `StandardTasks` has it's own `Helper` instance, then of course that instance won't have the event hooked up. Check my final edit at the end on how you could possibly solve it.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem with your info about the static context. I @shaamaan changed the event to static and the metod ConsoleUpdate also. i attach the listener with Helper.OnconsoleUpdate += eventhough i heared the static context could do some problems with the garbage collercor. Nice help anyways - really good explained